# How do I deserialize a JSON Array containing objects, in C# with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

```
[
   {
      "address":"addr1qx8trv7wualsnpj7xt"
   },
   {
      "address":"addr1qxkyl8vvmvy92ngm0y"
   },
   {
      "address":"addr1qywshwl6ud2myc0k2z"
   }
]
```

The above is a JSON file I'm trying to deserialize and read via NewtonsoftJSON.

However, I get the following error

> 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 2.'

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is parse all addresses and put them in a list.

Full Code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"[{""address"":""addr1qx8trv7wualsnpj7xt""}, {""address"":""addr1qxkyl8vvmvy92ngm0y""}, {""address"":""addr1qywshwl6ud2myc0k2z""}]";

            List<string> addresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);

            foreach (string address in addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(address);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(addresses);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create a class called address that as a string property called address then do  List<address > addresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<address >>(json); foreach (address a in addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.address );
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class called address that as a string property called address then do

```
List<address > addresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<address >>(json); 
foreach (address a in addresses) 
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(a.address ); 
} 

public class address 
{
   private string _address ="";

    // Declare a address property of type string:
    public string address 
    {
        get
        {
            return _address ;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I realized what I was doing wrong 

Comment: @Slaypoons you are welcome, please mark the answer up if it is useful

Comment: Says I need reputation :/

Comment: @Slaypoons not really, just to let others use the answer, I marked the one below as up as I like AnonymousType.

Answer (score 2):

The quick way to do this is to define an anonymous type that has an `address` property, then use `DeserializeAnonymousType`.

```
string json = @"[{""address"":""addr1qx8trv7wualsnpj7xt""}, {""address"":""addr1qxkyl8vvmvy92ngm0y""}, {""address"":""addr1qywshwl6ud2myc0k2z""}]";
string[] list = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, new[] { new { address = "" } }).Select(x => x.address).ToArray();

foreach (var item in list) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Output:

```
addr1qx8trv7wualsnpj7xt
addr1qxkyl8vvmvy92ngm0y
addr1qywshwl6ud2myc0k2z
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, as did the one below. I'll be using that since I understand it better, but I'll definitely look into what the AnonymousType thing is. 